# Latex Installation

Tags: software-installation

How to install Latex in Ubuntu 17.04..
I have tried installing through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
```

It shows this error...

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blahota/wxmaxima/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.    
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.    
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.    
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.    
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.    
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Comment: Please don't use uppercase letters so much... use sparingly

Comment: That PPA doesn't support Ubuntu 17.04 anyway.

Comment: . . . perhaps because the [version of texlive in the zesty repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/texlive) is already 2016.20170123-5

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support guys. But I have found the solution.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

It worked for me.